# why can't I get git log to use the "since" and "until" parameters?

Tags: git, logging, git-log

from the git log help page:

> since..until    Show only commits
>   between the named two commits. When
>   either  or  is omitted,
>   it defaults to HEAD, i.e. the tip of
>   the current branch. For a more
>   complete list of ways to spell 
>   and , see gitrevisions(7).

but i can't get it to work. `git log 32c67ec..HEAD` shows some unknown, large subset of the entire log.

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure, the SHA1 is correct?

Comment: Hmm, just tried the same thing on another repo, it works properly.

Comment: Has 32c67ec diverged from HEAD? or is it an ancestor?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on the correct branch or specify the branch explicitly. Head may not be where you thought it would be.